# What kind of Julet cut off plug is this?

Tags: brakes, electric-bike

I own a NCM Moscow that uses a [Tektro EL555-RT](https://www.leoncycle.com.au/left-e-brake-lever) with this Julet 2pin connector

[image]
[image]

I would like to replace the braking system with a hydraulic one however I simply can't find brakes with this connection, the Julet ones are all round plugs. Is this a custom plug or there could be adapters at least?